# Array.each do vs Array do - what is the difference?

Tags: ruby

I am at a loss to explain the result of evaluating the second code block (not using [`.each`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-each)).

```
Array.new(3).each do |i|; p i; end
# nil
# nil
# nil
#=> [nil, nil, nil]

Array.new(3) do |i|; p i; end
# 0
# 1
# 2
#=> [0, 1, 2]      # <-- ???
```

I understand that:

1. `Array.new(#)` invokes an Array with the corresponding # of `nil` values, and
2. The call to the `.each` method with `do |i|` iterates over (enumerates?) each index value (=nil),
3. `p` prints that value, and
4. the code block ends.

I am confused as to how removing the `.each` method call results in the `Array.new` indexes getting assigned values.

Of note, an error is generated with the same `do` block after an explicitly declared array of nil values (if I am describing it correctly?)

```
[nil, nil, nil].each do |i|; p i; end
# nil
# nil
# nil
#=> [nil, nil, nil]

[nil, nil, nil] do |i|; p i; end
# SyntaxError: (irb):4: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block, expecting end-of-input
# [nil, nil, nil] do |i|; p i; end
#                   ^
#        from C:/Ruby22/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

I am assuming the [`do`](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/files/keywords_rb.html#M000015) code block start paired with `Array.new` is making some kind of a difference. Any explanation of what is going on here would be very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array.new(3).each { ... }` creates a new array with the size `3` and calls `each` on that array.

Whereas `Array.new(3) { ... }` creates an array of the size `3` and sends the block as a second argument to the `new` method. When you call `new` with a block then the return value of the block is used to initialize the array.

See the docs about [`Array#new`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-c-new)

Answer (score 2):

[Documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-c-new) says:

```
new(size=0, default=nil)
new(array)
new(size) {|index| block }
```

> In the last form, an array of the given size is created. Each element in this array is created by passing the element’s index to the given block and storing the return value.

You get your elements assigned by pure chance (`p` returns value it printed, making it return value of the block, making it value of the corresponding array element). Had you used `puts` (which always returns `nil`), you'd get nil elements in the array and printed 0, 1, 2 to the standard output, which would add to the confusion, I imagine :)

Comment: ha - yes, `puts` did just that. Your edit was helpful!